# Mongodb: return objects from document array

Tags: php, mongodb, shell, nosql

In the following collection, how would I return all documents, but remove objects from the `foos` array where `bar != 'en'`

```
{
    "name": "Item 1"
    "foos": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "bar": "en"
        }
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "bar": "fr"
        }
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "bar": "en"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily. You need this feature: http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1831

Comment: You will have to do this on the client with a second round of filtering.

Answer (score -1):

MongoDB hasn't support virtual collections。So you can not get the part of sub-documents.Now you can create new document which you want to get the part of sub-documents。See http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142